# Magento remove zoom from product image

Tags: magento, zooming

Im not really familiar with Magento and i need to remove zoom effect from product image.
This is the code from /catalog/product/view/media.phtml inside template directory.

I tried to play around with if-else statement, but it seems im missing something because i am getting errors.

Is anybody more familiar with this to take a look?
Thanks a bunch!

```
    <div class="product-image">
<?php if ($scrollStatus): ?>
    <div id="jp-container" class="jp-container" style="height:500px;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><?php
            $_img = '<img src="'.$helpImg->getImg($_product, 'image', $imgSize, null).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
                echo $_img;
        ?></a>
        <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        function jspaneStart(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                maxHeight = 0;
                jQuery('#jp-container a').each(function(){
                    if(jQuery(this).height() > maxHeight){
                        maxHeight = jQuery(this).height();
                    }
                });
                maxHeight = maxHeight+(maxHeight/100)*<?php echo $scrollimagesHeight; ?>;
                jQuery('#jp-container').css('height', maxHeight);
                jQuery('#jp-container').jScrollPane();
            }, 500);
        }
        jspaneStart();
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
            jspaneStart();
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php else: ?>
    <a id='zoom' class="cloud-zoom" data-zoom="showTitle: false, adjustX: -5, adjustY:-5, tint: '#fff', tintOpacity:0.6, position:'inside'" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>"><?php
            $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$helpImg->getImg($_product, 'image', $imgSize, null).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
                echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
        ?></a>
        <?php /* Label New */ echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsMinimalism')->getProductLabels($_product); ?>

    <?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
    <div class="more-views-container">
        <div class="more-views<?php if ($productpage_moreviews == 'moreviews_slider' && count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 3){echo ' slider-on';} ?>">
            <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
            <?php if ($productpage_moreviews == 'moreviews_slider' && count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 3): ?>
            <div id="more-views-slider" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                <ul class="carousel-ul">
                <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class='cloud-zoom-gallery' data-zoom="useZoom: 'zoom', smallImage: '<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, 'thumbnail', $imgSize, null, $_image->getFile()); ?>' " href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img <?php echo $helpImg->getImgSources($_product, 'thumbnail', 200, null, $_image->getFile()); ?> alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class = 'next'><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
            <div class = 'prev unselectable'><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <ul class="no-slider">
                <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class='cloud-zoom-gallery' data-zoom="useZoom: 'zoom', smallImage: '<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, 'thumbnail', $imgSize, null, $_image->getFile()); ?>' " href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img <?php echo $helpImg->getImgSources($_product, 'thumbnail', 200, null, $_image->getFile()); ?> alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
       <p class="availability in-stock"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
       <p class="availability out-of-stock"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable zoom from magento js.
just locate this file js\varien\product.js and comment this line

```
Event.observe(this.imageEl, 'dblclick', this.toggleFull.bind(this));
```

this line is responsible for image zoom by default.

Comment: Are you using magento default zoom or any other extension? This code was tested on magento clean version

Comment: I am not using default Magento theme, this is the one i have (http://meigeeteam.com/templates/minimalism/splash)

Im pretty sure that the fix could be done in the attached code above, but im getting erros no matter what i tried

Comment: This worked for me by deleting also the lines below this Event.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin`, then to `System -> Configuration`.Then go to `Manage -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output -> EcommerceTeam_CloudZoom -> Disable`. Click Save `Config`.

then Go to

```
System -> Configuration ->Catalog
```

On the next page under `Cloud Image Zoom` you will find a list of options to configure the module. 
`Enable Cloud Zoom` – when `no` is selected, the option disables the Cloud Zoom in your product images.

Click `‘Save Config’` at the top right when you are done.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Anju for your help, but this isnt working on my end (there is no EcommerceTeam_CloudZoom in Advanced), same thing in System-Conf-Catalog
http://i.imgur.com/etoXQ6J.png
But thanks for your help in any case :)

Comment: is there anything related to cloud zoom in your admin under configuration?

Comment: Check for this in admin. System -> Config / Theme Options / Product Page / Use zoom for product images

Comment: Nope, nothing http://i.imgur.com/NzmFiX9.png :(
No worries, wont keep you busy, thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always try disabling the module completely via the module's xml file in app/etc/modules

Your xml file that relates to the zoom module will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <module_name>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </module_name>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Simply set active to false

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me:

Add JS in media.phtml in your theme.

```
// ProductMediaManager is outside document.read scope
    if (typeof ProductMediaManager !== 'undefined') {

      // Override image zoom in /skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js
      // and prevent the zooming of images on hover
      ProductMediaManager.createZoom = function(image) { return; }

    }
```

I have found the answer form [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/how-to-remove-zoom-from-product-details-page-on-1-9-rwd-theme)

Thanks **"Patrick Ward"** for the great and simple Solution...